# WPF-MVVM-Bind window title to property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

My client application can connect to different server applications, therefore I would like to add the connection information to the window title dynamically. The title is bound to a property of the `ViewModel` and its `get` is called after starting the app, but than it doesn't get updated anymore, while other controls in the window are still working properly.

Here is the `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="{Binding Path=AppTitle}"
    Height="459"
    Width="810">
<Window.Resources>
    [...]
    <localVM:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Windows1ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Windows1ViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=ConnectionProperty}" Canvas.Right="0" Canvas.Bottom="0"/>
    </Canvas>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `Title` is bound to `AppTitle`, while `Label` is bound to `ConnectionProperty`, which is working fine. In the `XAML.cs` I set the `ViewModel` to the `DataContext` of the `View`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

The constructor of the `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    MenuItemViewModel server = new MenuItemViewModel { Text = ServerMenu };
    Menu.Add(server);
    AppTitle = "My application title";
    SetConnectionMenuEntry(false);
    //[.. dynamically build my menu ..]
}
```

After starting the application, the `Title` is shown correctly. Then I connect to a server:

```
private void ConnectToServer()
{
    //[.. connect to server ..]
    if (connected)
    {
        SetConnectionMenuEntry(true);
        ConnectionProperty = " - connected to " + serverProxy.url;
        AppTitle  = appTitle + connectionProperty;
    }
}
```

After this, the `Title` remains the same, while the `Label` gets the `ConnectionProperty` value.

Here is the definition of both properties, which is nearly identical:

```
    private string appTitle;
    public string AppTitle 
    {
        get { return appTitle; }
        set 
        {
            if (this.appTitle != value)
            {
                this.appTitle = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => AppTitle);
            }
        }
    }

    private string connectionProperty = "";
    public string ConnectionProperty
    {
        get { return this.connectionProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (this.connectionProperty != value)
            {
                this.connectionProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ConnectionProperty);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea why the `Title` is not updated, but the `Label`?

Comment: You have the `Windows1ViewModel` in the resources, however create a new DataContext for the window from code. Don't we have two instances of the ViewModel this way?

Comment: I am agree with Aphelion, I think that problem that you create twice (in code and in XAML)

Comment: I agree to you. You have one viewmodel for your window and one specially for your grid. The title is bound to window-viewmodel and the label to grid-viewmodel. You only update the second (menu also uses this) and so the title does not change. The solution is to remove the DataContext of the grid because it inherits the DataContext of the window.

Comment: @Aphelion: your comment should be posted as an answer.

Comment: The output only has two types of output, but both seem not to be connected to the problem:
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. 

The thread '<No Name>' (0x1c30) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: @Aphelion right, that was the problem. I added the ViewModel in the DataContext just some hours ago, because otherwise the AppTitle was not used when just referencing in the XAML. But I forgot to remove it than from XAML. Thanks :)
I put the changes in the post, but if you add an answer I will mark it.

Comment: @Mike No problem. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `Windows1ViewModel` in the `Grid.Resources`, however you create a new DataContext for the window from code. You have two instances of the ViewModel this way.

Answer (score 0):

*As stated by the original poster of the question:*

---

I commented out the lines I needed to remove to make it work properly :

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="{Binding Path=AppTitle}"
    Height="459"
    Width="810">
<Window.Resources>
    [...]
    <!-- <localVM:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Windows1ViewModel" /> [Edit: 2 times set] -->
</Window.Resources>
<Grid> <!-- Edit removed: DataContext="{StaticResource Windows1ViewModel}" -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=ConnectionProperty}" Canvas.Right="0" Canvas.Bottom="0"/>
    </Canvas>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```